# Length contraction: Is it permanent?

Tags: special-relativity

Lorentz contraction problem:
By Bertrand Boucquillon

Components of the problem:
- Bob (observer)
- 2 identical rods that both measure 1 meter. Let's call them rod X and rod Y
- Point A
- Point B

Scenario (step by step):
1) Bob is at point A, and is at rest with both rods in his hands
2) Bob throws rod X at 87% of the speed of light (.87c) at a target located at point B
3) rod X hits the target and is now at rest
4) Bob travels over to point B at walking speed, still holding rod Y in his hand
5) Bob is now at point B, at rest again, and grabs rod X from the target
6) Bob compares the length of rod X and rod Y

Question:
Is the length of rod X still the same as the length of rod Y? Please provide a detailed explanation of your answer and/or a source where the answer is explained properly.

Comment: Welcome Bernard ! For a homework, you must show what you did and where you got a difficulty. Else you would be downvoted and not helped

Comment: Hi. Thanks for addressing my question so quick, it is not a homework but a scenario I created myself to keep things simple in order to figure out the truth. I have seen multiple similar threads but nobody seems to be able to give an explanation.

Comment: This is a standard exercise; see problem 11.9 [here](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/chap11.pdf), which is identical to your problem. It also comes with a solution at the back.